# ¿como solucionar error 401 en todas las rutas spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Hola estoy tratando de crear un login api con spring boot para ello agregue `SecurityFilterChain` pues resulta que despues de hacer la configuracion ahora ya no puedo acceder a ninguna ruta todas me dan error 401 al menos probando por postman ya que esto solo lo usare para crear apis mi configuracion quedo asi

SecurityConfig.java

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

y el LoginController super basico

```
package com.example.streaming_nuevo.controllers;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/login")
public class LoginController {

    public String login() {
        return "Login exitoso";
    }
   
     @PostMapping("/logout")
    public String logout() {
              return "Logout exitoso";

    }
    
}
```

No puedo acceder a ninguna ruta todas me arrojan errores 401 no uso JWT ni nada por el estilo simplemente queria hacer un login usando postman y para ello agregue la clase SecurityConfig.java que ya comparti.
Intente todo desactivar csrf permitir todas las rutas con `.antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()` y cosas por el estilo pero no consigo dar con la respuesta.

Por ultimo esto fue lo que se agrego al pom para intentar hacer el login

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

No has declarado ninguna URL para permitir el login, por lo que todas las páginas están accesibles... pero sólo para usuarios logados.

Prueba a hacer algo como:

```java
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> 
                authz.anyRequest().permitAll()
            )
            .httpBasic(withDefaults())
            .formLogin((form) -> 
                form.loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            )
            .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }
```